# Cannot use free chat even though I turned 13 in Runescape

Tags: runescape

I'm a player of Runescape. I started playing it when there was no age limit for signing up (I was around 7, my elder brother helped me with it). Then I realized that I just had quick chat because I was below 13, and so I waited till I was 13 to continue playing it again. Now I am 13 and I still can't use free chat.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to get it? (I don't want to fax Jagex or anything)

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- You are on a quick-chat-only world.
- You got muted somehow. (Pmods can do that) --> Check your account for
  mutes
- I've read that you get **permanently** muted if you sign up with an age
  under 13. (I don't know if this is true or not)

I know you don't want to do this, but I think you have to contact Jagex. You could ask in the Runescape forum for help or write an email. Contact the jagexsupport (@JagexSupport) via Twitter is also an option.

Comment: I'm not muted. I never was able to use free chat anyway.  I can't post on the forums for the same reason. I don't know Jagex's e-mail, and I haven't heard too many good things about their customer service. What can I do, then?

Comment: You have to contact Jagex somehow. Like I said, Twitter is an option or maybe you can create a second account just to ask in the forums what to do with your main account. I would try twitter first and if you don't get an answer, create the other account.